# Помогите найти лексическую ошибку и исправить

Tags: лексика

Что неправильно в предложении

*Гражданка Сидорова обратилась с заявлением о разводе брака*?

Знаю, что ошибка есть, но не могу её найти,

спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Елена, ошибка в "разводе брака". Брак не разводят,  разводят людей.

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что в официально-деловой речи следует написать:

"Гражданка Сидорова обратилась с заявлением о расторжении брака".

Тот же самый вариант в разговорной речи выглядит так:

"Сидорова подала заявление на развод".